# Redirect to custom error page when a duplicate entry is made in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to redirect users to a custom error page (for example: error.php) when a duplicate entry is made, this is a sample of the insert statement, but I don't know how to do the redirecting.

```
$values = $_POST;
foreach ($values as &$value) {
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}

$sql1="INSERT INTO loan (loan_id)
VALUES ('$values[loan_id]')";

$result = mysql_query($sql1);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: How do you define a duplicate entry?

Comment: You have a unique constraint on that column, riiight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to redirect form input is using the [HTTP 303](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303) redirect.

To redirect at the current line, do so something like this, in PHP:

```
// Tell the browser to redirect
header('Location: /error.php', TRUE, 303);

// This ensures that the script doesn't continue
// Also, it shows the error on the off chance their browser doesn't redirect
die('Input error.');
```

You must ensure that you include the header function before any output.

Here it is in your code:

```
if (!$result) {
    header('Location: /error.php', TRUE, 303);
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    header('Location: /success.php', TRUE, 303);
    die('Success');
}
```

Comment: what about if the input is sucessful and i already having it redirecting to another page, can i have 2 redirects as in one to success.php if there is no error and another to error.php if there is an error

Comment: Yes. You just wrap an IF...ELSE statement around it. Redirect to one page on success, a different one on error. I've updated my answer to show how you'd implement it inside of your code.

Comment: To generate the error inline, you'd just do `include 'error.php'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect using `header()`:

```
$url = "error.php";
header("Location: " . $url);
```

Make sure this is executed before the HTML headers are sent!

Comment: Note that it has to be called before any output is sent!

Comment: what about if the input is sucessful and i already having it redirecting to another page, can i have 2 redirects as in one to success.php if there is no error and another to error.php if there is an error

Comment: @dames: Just use a simple `if` to determine which page you want to redirect based on your error.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather check for existing data before inserting than just insert it:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM myDB WHERE loan_id = " . $values["loan_id"];
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
   echo "Wrong input";
} else {
   echo "right input";
}
```

Instead of the string echos you can load whole pages according to your need or use redirect, if you didnt output anything already

Comment: True, but its much clearer what you're doing. And since every code will grow eventually or be copied to similar cases you can easily see, where you have to distinguish between different errors.

Comment: Just to clarify, I meant twice as much work for the server. "Too much work" is never an excuse for a developer. :) If you want to check more than if it's a duplicate key then you'd have to do something similar to your suggestion, but since we're only checking if it's duplicate, checking for an error on insert is the most efficient way. It's just one trip to the server rather than two. In your case, I'd at least select just the load_id column.