# Prevent duplicate data being entered into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make my email subscription service reject emails that already exist within my database so users don't subscribe the same email twice. this is what I have but its not working, any ideas?

```
<?php 
    if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) 
        exit();

    $vars = array('email');
    $verified = TRUE;
    foreach($vars as $v) {
        if(!isset($_POST[$v]) || empty($_POST[$v])) {
            $verified = FALSE;
        }
    }   
    if(!$verified) {
        echo "<p style='color:white; margin-top:25px;'>*Email required*</p>";
        exit();
    }
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if($_POST['submit']) echo "<p style='color:white; margin-top:25px;'>*Check your inbox*        </p>";

    // Create connection
    $con=mysqli_connect("mysql.host","user","password","dbname");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql="INSERT INTO emails (email)    VALUES  ('$_POST[email]')";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emails WHERE email='$email'",($con));
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) != 1)
    {
        echo "email already exists";
        // redirect back to form and populate with 
        // data that has already been entered by the user
    }


    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Just a quick note. You're mixing `mysqli_` and `mysql_`

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? For one thing - your check to see if the email exists is after you try to insert it. For another, you seem to be mixing mysql_ and mysqli_ functions.

Comment: Beat you by 1 second @andrewsi lol too funny.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - I hope you didn't take my comment on your answer seriously!

Comment: Actually yes (didn't want a downvote), it's better to use parameter binding. I guess that should have been `WHERE email=?` ? @andrewsi

Comment: @Fred-ii- - that'll do it. :)

Comment: Got it. Cheers fellas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysqli_num_rows($query)` instead of `mysql_num_rows($query)`

```
       $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM emails WHERE email='".$email."'");

        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){

            echo "email already exists";
        }else{
            $sql="INSERT INTO emails (email)    VALUES  ('".$_POST[email]."')";
            if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
            {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to let MySQL reject the duplicate e-mail address is to make the field unique (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

```
ALTER TABLE emails ADD UNIQUE (email)
```

However, MySQL will not return a warning

Comment: I think this approach is best, having 'email' a unique field will prevent redundant checking code, just try to insert, if you get an error due to DUPLICATE KEY you know you already have that record. Also since 'email' is a UNIQUE KEY now, it is a very good candidate for searching.

Comment: Because?..:) I know it's not the best site overall, but in this particular case their explaination was pretty clear

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you're mixing `MySQLi_` with `MySQL_` so stick with `MySQLi_` and modify the rest of your code accordingly.

This is the logic I use in my scripts, using `?` instead of `'$email'`

```
$query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM emails WHERE email=?");
// $query = $con->query("SELECT email FROM emails WHERE email=?");
// you may need to use that one --^ if checking a particular column

$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($numrows > 0){
die("Email already exists in the database, please try again.");
}
```

You can use this method, binding parameters. Assuming your column is named `email`

```
$query = "SELECT email FROM emails WHERE email=?";

if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)){

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            $stmt->store_result();

            $email_check= "";         
            $stmt->bind_result($email_check);
            $stmt->fetch();

            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1){

            echo "That Email already exists.";
            exit;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No parameter binding? Shocking! :D

Comment: Undeleted. @andrewsi better yes?

Comment: added a `bind_param` feature ;-) @andrewsi

Answer (score 0):

Beside mixing mysql and mysli

Use > not !=

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 1)
```

But this approach means you already have duplicates.

[Maybe this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163076/redirect-to-custom-error-page-when-a-duplicate-entry-is-made-in-mysql) after you put an unique index on the email column.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the other answers, you mixed mysqli and mysql functions.

for exemple in both these lines you use mysql instead of mysqli functions.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emails WHERE email='$email'",($con));
if(mysql_num_rows($query) != 1)
```

**I also think your code is easily SQL Injectable.**

You are using $_POST["email"] in your insert query, without sanitizing it.

Have a look to at least the [sql injection wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Actually his fault is not, not filtering it, rather using it inside his SQL instead of passing it as arguments. Filtering is not the right way to protect from SQLi, using argument based SQL (i.e. "email = ?") and then to the SQL function the email as an argument is the right approach

Comment: Interesting, can you provide some details or a source

Comment: You are asking me? :) if so I am referring to this: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be as follows,

First, create a UNIQUE KEY of the email column, and then:

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (/*etc*/) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE /*set a column equal to itself*/
```

This allows you to attempt inserting into the database, and you can choose whether or not the query throws an error. If you want it to throw an error, then simply do not use `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, and then catch the SQLException that is thrown from the query and tell the user that the email already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Add a unique constraint to the email column.

Test for error returned on insert or update. I believe the code may be influenced if it is a primary key, foreign key, unique constraint on an index.

With PHP you can use

```
if( mysql_errno() == X) {
    // Duplicate VALUE
} else {
    // fail
}
```

You can test it yourself with a duplicate email or [here are the mysql_errNo return values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-errno.php)

For non PHP, to determine correct error code test it yourself with a duplicate email or look at the following.

[MySQL Errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html)