# How can I alert a user that an entry has already been input into the database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently trying to ensure no duplicate emails are allowed to be entered within my mySQL database, I've marked stud_email as unique within the database I'm just struggling to alert the message. This is what I've got so far, am I on the correct path?

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $check = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM students WHERE stud_email = '$email'");
    $checkrows = mysqli_num_rows($check);

    if ($checkrows > 0) {
        echo '<script>alert("Student email already exists")</script>';
    } else {
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent duplicate data being entered into mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081424/prevent-duplicate-data-being-entered-into-mysql-database)

Comment: call that email specifically , using : select email from students where email = check email and then continue.

Comment: I believe OP is asking how to (accurately) detect a DUPLICATE KEY error from the database. This is not a duplicate of "Prevent duplicate data being entered into mysql database"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a row exists in MySQL? (i.e. check if an email exists in MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252904/how-to-check-if-a-row-exists-in-mysql-i-e-check-if-an-email-exists-in-mysql)

Answer (score -2):

```
$check = mysqli_query (SELECT count(*) FROM students WHERE stud_email = '$email');
```

Use Count to check whether the email is already in your database. If the count is greater than 1 then check it using `IF` condition in your JSP

```
if($check>0) {
     echo '<script>alert("Student email already exists")</script>';
}
```

Comment: I'm now getting this error 'mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result' on the $checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($check); line? do you know why this would be

Comment: you need not need this line `$checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($check);`

Comment: I'm not getting any errors now but I don't get any alert messages @vinieth

Comment: @thomaswalker Did you check that `$check` returning value > 0. Check that by printing it